# Cannot find a declared module when running a Jest unit test

Tags: jestjs, spfx

I am trying to test a spfx webpart component and I am getting the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'WebPartContentStrings' from 'WebContentContainer.tsx'
```

I did some digging and I found that inside my component I do the following:

```
import * as strings from "WebPartContentStrings";
```

And I have this file:

```
declare module 'WebPartContentStrings' {
  const strings: IWebPartContentStrings;
  export = strings;
}
```

However, it seems when I mock the component Jest cannot interpret the import instruction correctly and cannot find the module even though the application can find it when I host it on a server. Is there a way to import the strings in a different way for Jest?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.It has to be fixed when 'react' the 'jsx' property in tsconfig.json.

For example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

> import * as strings from "WebPartContentStrings";

pass the strings of your webpart as props to the component and use those the way you use normal props. For example:

Props interface definition:

```
export interface IYourComponentsProps { strings: IWebPartContentStrings }
```

Using some of the strings in your react component's render function:

```
<p>{this.props.strings.exampleString}</p>
```

This will fix the import issue you're facing.

Cheers.